# Draw these shapes

Tags: code-golf, image-processing

Given: a width, a height, and a set of sets of points. Output: An image where each set of points is connected and colored in (like a shape). Each shape *must* be a different color from all of the other shapes, but **the actual color doesn't matter as long as each color is distinct**. The shapes must be in order; whether you start at the end or the beginning of the set doesn't matter, though. **The dots must be connected in the order they're given in the set.**

Output formats are in accordance with standard image rules.

### Examples

```js
//the code here has nothing to do with the actual challenge and just shows examples

document.getElementById("one").getContext("2d").fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
const ctx = document.getElementById("two").getContext("2d")
ctx.fillStyle = "black"
ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(0,0);ctx.lineTo(0,300);ctx.lineTo(300,0);ctx.closePath();ctx.fill()
ctx.fillStyle = "lime"
ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(200,0);ctx.lineTo(600,0);ctx.lineTo(300,300);ctx.closePath();ctx.fill()
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px dotted black}
```

```html
<pre>Width: 500, Height: 500, Set: [[[0, 0], [0, 300], [300, 300], [300, 0]]]</pre>
<canvas id="one" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<pre>Width: 600, Height: 300, Set:
[
  [[0,0], [0,300], [300,0]],
  [[200,0], [600,0], [300,300]]
]</pre>
<canvas id="two" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

Scoring is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: I meant to ask this question in the Sandbox but what qualities as a "different" colour? Is `#000000` different to `#000001`?

Comment: Also, what output formats are allowed? Is a base-64 encoded PNG outputted as s string OK? Or the XML markup of an SVG?

Comment: How are we supposed to connect the shapes? Suppose it's a pentagon. Which points go with which points?

Comment: @SHaggy I am assuming that this question is using a standard image I/O format

Comment: I am voting to close because it doesn't say how we should connect the dots.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had stuff to do. The colors can be different but the difference between them doesn't matter. Output formats are in accordance with standard image rules. The dots should be connected in the order they're given in the set

Comment: What winding rule should be used?

Comment: What do you mean by "winding rule"?

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>122</s> 71 bytes

```r
function(w,h,p){plot.new();plot.window(c(0,w),c(0,h));polygon(p,c=1:8)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtRCsIwEESvk4VBNimBovTDC3gIo7GFkoRSWUQ8e9wY/FjmMbNvq3Gq8ZnCvuRkBDMKvcua90O6i6HTD2VJtywmGIYQWsykU15fD5UKwmSPI31qNAMzvN52VUUFq@yYm6SBoaNvT4TLudUetrf8B6e78x1HBhNR/QI)

[RDRR - actually shows graphics](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(w%2Ch%2Cp)%7Bplot.new()%3Bplot.window(c(0%2Cw)%2Cc(0%2Ch))%3Bpolygon(p%2Cc%3D1%3A8)%7D%0Af(300%2C500%2Crbind(c(100%2C200)%2Cc(200%2C300)%2Cc(50%2C50)%2CNA%2Cc(25%2C100)%2Cc(0%2C100)%2Cc(250%2C250)%2Cc(280%2C0))))

A function that takes arguments width, height and a matrix of points detailing the shapes. Each shape is separated by a row of NAs. Output is a plot to the screen of the shapes.